# Logging on to Cisco Aironet Wireless Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Somebody (before my time) has set up a Cisco Aironet Router in my local church.  Apparently, it is plugged into the Pastor's router at his house and broadcasting it to the church building.

Here is a picture of the back of the thing:
[image]

Now it seems to be broadcasting a wireless network but nobody knows the password.  I've got a laptop and a cat5 cable (because I thought I could just plug in to it and get to the config like a normal router) but that seems to be useless.

Can anyone help me make any headway with this? We just want to be able to connect.

Comment: Any router should be password protected too. So, you need to ask the network's owner for access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be an autonomous* Cisco Aironet 1252G AP.

The documentation is here:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/wireless/aironet-1250-series-access-point/model.html

Of particular interest might be the Quick Start Guide here:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/1250/quick/guide/ap1250qs.html

If you have the right kind of RJ45 serial console cable (the infamous Cisco "blue cable"), you can connect to the console and try to log on as the default admin account, which is username "Cisco", password "Cisco" (case-sensitive, no quotes).

If that doesn't work, you'll probably have to reset the AP to factory defaults and then set it up again from scratch. The instructions are in the Quick Start Guide, but I'll reproduce them here:

> **Resetting to Default Configuration**
>
> **Note** *These steps reset all configuration settings to factory defaults, including passwords, WEP keys, the IP address, and the
>   SSID.*
>
> If you forget the password that allows you to configure the access
>   point, you may need to completely reset the configuration. You can use
>   the MODE button on the access point or your web browser to reset the
>   configuration.
>
> **Using the MODE Button**
>
> Follow these steps to delete the current configuration and return all
>   access point settings to the factory defaults:
>
> **Step 1** If the access point is mounted using its mounting plate, remove it to gain access to the MODE button.
>
> **Step 2** Disconnect power from the access point (the power jack for external power or the Ethernet cable for in-line power).
>
> **Step 3** Press and hold the MODE button while you reconnect power to the access point.
>
> **Step 4** Continue holding the MODE button until the Ethernet LED turns amber (approximately 2 to 3 seconds), then release the button.
>
> **Step 5** After the access point reboots, you must reconfigure it using the web browser interface, the Telnet interface, or connecting
>   to the access point console port.

Please note that it looks like your 1252 is an 802.11g model from about 2003. If it hasn't had any 802.11n upgrade modules added to it later, then it's been outright obsolete since 2007. You could walk into any store with a consumer electronics department/aisle and buy the cheapest wireless router you can find, for $15-20, and it'll be faster than that 1252. Or take Wirecutter's budget pick for $70 and have a decent box. So if it takes you 30 minutes of fussing with that 1252 to break into it and get it set up again, you would have come out ahead by just replacing it with literally the cheapest thing you can find at the nearest store that sells home wireless routers. Of course it wouldn't be as rugged and reliable as that Cisco box once was, so you may need to reboot it from time to time, but it'll still probably be better for its users than a Cisco AP from a decade and a half ago.